# How to include rowspan and colspan dynamically inside <td> tag based on some conditions

Tags: javascript, html-table

I know I can include `<td colspan=10>` statically when I want to merge the columns, but if I need to check some conditions and based on that only I need to merge then how this could be done?

My idea was like this:

```
var span="";
if(some condition)
span="colspan=10";
```

and then setting this variable inside `<td>` as:

```
<td +span+>
```

but it doesn't work like that… Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Can you do it with server-side code? Are the conditions applied at the time the page is first served, or later?

Comment: Actually this is a phone-gap based project in which i am creating the required table with inner html dynamically…

Comment: When the page is served i get the response through wcf service then at table formatting time i need to check for condition and based on that i need to include colspan or rowspan

Comment: _"i am creating the required table with inner html dynamically"_ - Then yes, you can do it with something like `"<td " + span + ">"` (make sure `span` is set to an empty string when not needed, which you could do with `var span = (someCondition) ? "colspan='10'" : "";`). Show more of your actual code for more specific help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var span='';
var table='';

if(some condition)
  span="colspan=10";


var table="<tr><td"+span+"></td></tr>":
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<table id="table" border=2>
<tr id="row1">
<td id="tableCellID">foo</td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>foo</td><td>foo</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="button();" text="Change"/>
<script language="javascript">
var i = 0;
function button(){
var td = document.getElementById("tableCellID");

if(i==0){
td.setAttribute("colspan", 2);

i=1;
}else{
    td.setAttribute("colspan", 1);

    i=0;
}
}
</script>
```

This is how you can dynamically set the attribute colspan.  You will see that changing the colspan of one cell will effect the layout of the entire table.  You will need to deal with each cell in the row.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do is, if you able to set an `id` in your `td`

`<td id="foo">`

in your javascript, you can add attributes like this,

`document.getElementById("foo").colSpan="10";`

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("tr.total td").style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
document.querySelector("tr.grand td:nth-child(1)").colSpan="2";
document.querySelector("tr.grand td:nth-child(2)").remove();
```

```css
table, table td {border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px 10px; border-spacing:0px;}
.grand{font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td>Column</td>
 <td>Value</td>
</tr>
<tr class="total">
 <td>Sub Cost</td>
 <td>$500</td>
</tr>
<tr class="grand">
 <td>Amount $1000</td>
  <td>Remove Me</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck